# Call of a package in general. Access and visibility of stylefiles

Tags: package-writing, ctan

i.e. the `moderncv-package` has several sty-files (i.e. `moderncvbodyi.sty`). Apparently, I can not call `\usepackage{moderncvbodyi}` from another document than a moderncv-document. This means, that the visibility of `moderncvbodyi` is limited to `moderncv.cls`.

The basic question is: What defines the accessibility and visibility of sty-files.

Why I want to know this: I'm creating a package and want to know, if there is the need to split it into several packages when uploading them to ctan (they are not ready yet).

The packages are:
A songbook package which provides environments to create songbook-"databases";
A songbooky-package, which provides a class for creating small songbooks easily. It uses the songbook-"databases" and therefore the songbook-package;
A fill-pages-package which fills the page count to a number dividable by a custom number (default 4);

These packages can be used independently in different context (i.e. songbook-package can be used in a scientific report also).

Comment: You can call `\usepackage{moderncvbodyi}`, the file is visible, but as it relies on commands from the main moderncv.cls you get errors so the file is not usable with other class. How you split your package in files and subfiles is your own decision.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Definitely not, because if I use `moderncvfooti` and use the command `\footsymbol`, it throws an error `! LaTeX Error: File 'moderncvfooti.sty' not found.` If I copy the definition of `\footsymbol`, it works without any flaws.

Comment: Well above your are speeking of moderncv**bodyi**, not moderncv**footi**. Beside this the style loads fine for me `(d:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvfooti.sty`. (But this style isn't usable outside the class neither).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This has just been an example. Choose any sty-file you want. As you see, the whole path is needed and just `\usepackage{moderncvfooti}` will result in an error. My question is about the principle. If I use `\documentclass{moderncv}` I don't need to insert the full path to the class file. Inside `moderncv` a simple `\RequirePackage{moderncvfooti}` is sufficient. Why not in the first case? The question is: How is this mechanism controlled?

Comment: Get it in your head: I can use `\usepackage{moderncvfooti}` in any document and this will load the sty from the path mentioned above. If it doesn't work for you then you either don't have moderncvfooti.sty at all, e.g. because your moderncv package is too old, or your fndb is not up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was mistakeable by you. You were right about the update, but this is still no reason the be rude.

Comment: Well I told you twice that you are mistaken. But you didn't take this as a pointer to reconsider your own claim. Instead you simply dismissed my answers and even insinuated that I'm to dumb to understand that you want to load a package without using an absolute path. I don't think that you would have paid attention if I hadn't started to get a bit rude.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To clarify: That was mistakable expressed by you. Therefore, I misunderstood it. Otherwise I would have written that you have misunderstood it.